# Dúvida no funcionamento do Migration automático com MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Com migration automático o banco de dados é atualizado também quando houver exclusão de alguma propriedade da minha classe modelo? Ou seja, além de ele incluir um novo atributo se for acrescentado algo a minha classe, ele também remove? Como o exemplo abaixo, estou tentando fazer com que ele remova o campo CEP que foi acrescentando e está vazio, mas isso não está acontecendo. Retorna uma exceção **AutomaticDataLossException**

**Início**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Aluno aluno = new Aluno
    {
        AlunoId = 1,
        Nome = "Cláudia",
        Email = "claudia@email.com"
    };

    using (var db = new DBContexto())
    {
        db.Aluno.Add(aluno);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Model Class**

```
public class Aluno
{
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    //public string Cep { get; set; }
}
```

**Contexto**

```
public class DBContexto : DbContext
{
    public DBContexto()
        : base(@"data source=(local); initial catalog=DbAluno; integrated security=true;")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DBContexto>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DBContexto, Configuration>());
    }
    public DbSet<Aluno> Aluno { get; set; }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ConsoleApplication1.DBContexto>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ConsoleApplication1.DBContexto context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Com migration automático o banco de dados é atualizado também quando houver exclusão de alguma propriedade da minha classe modelo? Ou seja, além de ele incluir um novo atributo se for acrescentado algo a minha classe, ele também remove?

Sim. A coluna é excluída.

> Como o exemplo abaixo, estou tentando fazer com que ele remova o campo CEP que foi acrescentando e está vazio, mas isso não está acontecendo. Retorna uma exceção `AutomaticDataLossException`.

Sim, isto é uma proteção do Entity Framework para que dados importantes não sejam perdidos. É ligado por padrão.

Como você está num ambiente de desenvolvimento, pode incluir o seguinte na configuração de *Migrations* para evitar essa verificação:

```cs
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MeuProjetoContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigada!